# Sending A Document To MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have recently been trying to use MongoDB with Python and Node JS.

Here are the following outcomes:

I believe I have connected by navigating to my bin folder in MongoDB and typing `mongod`
https://gyazo.com/e4068d1ffb533050e4679a8213f56b25, 
[image]

also (in a separate command prompt) typed `net start MongoDB`.
and  https://gyazo.com/7497f959ce01d66116be6b5fe0937990. 
[image]

These are both run when I do my script.

For Python, I have `pip` installed pymongo.
[This](https://gyazo.com/6e942e95cb3315023c43cd72cc2cfceb) 
 is my code:

```
import pymongo, datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

db = client.Experience
collection = db.Reputation

post = {"author": "William",
        "text": "May you help?",
        "date": datetime.datetime.now()}

collection.insert_one(post)
```

Once run, it displays the >>> and nothing else. In JS the same thing also happens; I used another documentation for JS as well. I am stuck and have no idea - does anyone know?

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images!

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/fxgyb There - couldn't find how to do blocks.

Comment: Sorry, you need to paste the code into the question. As StackOverflow is a Q&A knowledge base, links (which may disappear over time) are not the right way to provide code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not see them?

Comment: Moved code from ghostbin.com and images from gyazo.com

Comment: Your mongo server has started, and the python code that you have created produces the desired result creating a database named Experience with a collection named Reputation and the post. Are you expecting to see the results? either include a success print  in your code or enter the mongo shell by entering mongo in the terminal, then show dbs then show collections and finally db.Reputation.find() to see your post.

Comment: Hi @ChuckLaPress; Thank you! By using find_one in my code it has successfully retrieved a document. But do you know why it is not showing up in my MongoDB Compas?

Comment: @William, In your Compass launch, connect to host  Hostname localhost, Port 27017 enter connect database Experience Collection Reputation doesn't appear?

Comment: In the upright corner of compass do you see the database you are connected to? I have replicated your python code and successfully created and inserted this document and see it in my compass viewing localhost

Comment: Be sure your local mongo server is running while examining compass

Comment: @ChuckLaPress Thanks for your help! I can now see all my documents. Would you mind explaining why it doesn't show up when I log onto it as my profile? Is it because I have the free version or something?

Comment: @William, I am unsure what you mean, Are you seeing the array of objects in Compass or in the mongo shell? When you say " I can now see all my documents", which are you referring to. I have a free account that I am capable of viewing both localhost mongo instance as well as a free Atlas host cluster, so paid vs free is not an issue with that regards. I am glad that your capable of viewing your files and suggest posting another question on SO regarding Compass if you could. Thanks Chuck